# Send Node.js ServerResponse back to client with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with a Node.js Express application, and trying to use a library that makes an HTTP request, and returns a Node.js ServerResponse object. I'd like to send this back to the browser somehow using Express. I could look at the ServerResponse object, and set everything (status, body, cookies, headers, etc) in the Express response manually, but I was hoping there would be a nicer way. Is there some nice way I can send a ServerResponse object back to the client with Express?

Comment: You mean like `res.json(res)`?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, your library returns an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage` class](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) which implements [`stream.Readable` interface](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). In this case you should be able to [pipe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) incoming message to the client:

```
request(uri).pipe(res);
```

Here is a complete example that uses [`request` module](https://github.com/request/request):

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  var uri = 'http://stackoverflow.com' + req.url;
  request(uri).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You're right, it is an instance of http.IncomingMessage! This worked, but it only piped the body of the response, and not the headers, etc.